# How can I use the Python nftables library in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Debian has a package called `python3-nftables`. You can install it with `apt`. It lets you interact with nftables (the modern iptables replacement).

Normally, when `apt` has a Python library, the library can also be found on pypi.org, which means the library can be included in a `requirements.txt` file, and be installed along with any other Python libraries when the virtual environment is being set up. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, this package is not available on pypi.org.

If I install it with `apt`, and run `python3`, I can `import nftables`. Great.
The problem is that when you enter a virtual environment and try the same thing - `import nftables`, it won't be found, because by default, the virtual environment ignores any system libraries installed with `apt`.

You can, of course, tell it to include those with `--system-site-packages` when creating the virtual environment, but there's a reason this isn't enabled by default.

After installing `python3-nftables` with `apt`, I can also copy the package (`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nftables`) directly into my project folder, and include it in my project's git repo. That works, but seems a bit hackey.

Is there a proper way to install the `nftables` library inside of the virtual environment, instead of installing it system-wide, and forcing the virtual environment to see it?

Comment: Do you have a question that this doesn't already answer?: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: @jjramsey ya, I do - the question I wrote above. It's not answered by that link in any way, shape or form.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python3-nftables -> https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/python3-nftables -> (in the right column) https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/nftables -> (browse source code) https://sources.debian.org/src/nftables/1.0.0-1/ -> https://sources.debian.org/src/nftables/1.0.0-1/py/

Comment: @phd I have access to the source code at `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nftables`. How does that help me run it in the virtual environment? This appears to be no better than the hackey solution I covered above in my second-last paragraph.

Comment: Just include the lib in package like you are and you will be fine. If its not available on pypi just bring the files in yourself, you have to do this with Lambda functions so its not uncommon to include libraries for python that doesnt involve pip as not all devices have apt/pip/pipenv or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is at https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-netfilter-team/pkg-nftables/-/tree/master/py. There is `setup.py` so you can do

```
pip install 'git+https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-netfilter-team/pkg-nftables#egg=nftables&subdirectory=py'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a copy of the module and uploaded it to PyPI to use it in a project of mine.
https://github.com/ansibleguy/python3-nftables

```bash
pip install ansibleguy-nftables
```

You could install it or create a pypi account yourself and create your own package if you want to 'control the source'.